# Remove a Character From String in Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, stringbuilder, stringindexoutofbounds

I'm trying to concatenate a string with itself and remove all *capital letters* from the resultant string.

*Here is my code:*

```
public String removeCapitals(String A) {
    StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder(A+A);
    int n = B.length();

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(B.charAt(i)>='A' && B.charAt(i)<='Z'){
            B.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }

    return B.toString();
}
```

I'm getting Exception saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.charAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:237)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.charAt(StringBuilder.java:76)
at Solution.removeCapitals(Solution.java:10)
at Main.main(Main.java:190)
```

Can someone help me to understand the issue.

Comment: `n` contains the length of the StringBuilder before you start the loop.  When you call `B.deleteCharAt`, the StringBuilder’s length is no longer the same as the value of `n`.

Comment: The issue is that you define "n" as being the length of B (let's say 6), then while looping you remove one or more characters from B (so its length becomes less than 6), but the loop still goes up to 6 and so it gets to a point where it touches an index that doesn't exist anymore (for example 6 itself), causing an String out of bound exception

Answer (score 3):

If at least one removal succeeds, at some point your code will attempt to access an invalid index that exceeds the length of a `StringBuilder`.

It happens because the variable `n` remain unchanged. You should change the condition to be bound to the current size of `StringBuilder` and decrement the index at each removal, or iterate backwards (as shown in another answer).

Also condition `B.charAt(i)>='A' && B.charAt(i)<='Z'` can be replaced with:

```
Character.isUpperCase(b.charAt(i))
```

Which is more descriptive.

That's how it might look like:

```
 public static String removeCapitals(String a) {
    
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(a + a);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(b.charAt(i))) {
            b.deleteCharAt(i); // which can be combined with the next line `b.deleteCharAt(i--);` - previous value of `i` would be used in the call `deleteCharAt()` and variable `i` will hold a value decremented by 1
            i--;
        }
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

Method `deleteCharAt()` runs in a linear time, because it shifts all subsequent characters in the underlying array bytes. Each upper-case letter will trigger these shifts and in the worst case scenario, it would result in the *quadratic* overall time complexity **O(n ^ 2)**.

You make your method more performant and much more concise without using loops and `StringBuilder`. This code will run in a linear time **O(n)**.

```
public static String removeCapitals(String a) {
    
    return a.replaceAll("\\p{Upper}", "").repeat(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a character you change the length of the StringBuilder.  But `n` still has the original length. So you will eventually exceed the size of the `StringBuilder`.  So start from the end and move backwards.  That way, any deletions will come `after` (based on relative indices) the next position so the index will be within the modified `StringBuilder` size.  In addition, deleting from the end is more efficient since there is less copying to do in the StringBuilder.

```
public String removeCapitals(String A) {
    StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder(A+A);
    int n = B.length(); 

    for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(B.charAt(i)>='A' && B.charAt(i)<='Z'){
            B.deleteCharAt(i);
        }
    }

    return B.toString();
}
```

Comment: …but if you really want to minimize the copying overhead, you don’t perform the `A+A` operation before removing the unwanted letters nor copy everything to the buffer beforehand. `StringBuilder B = new StringBuilder(A.length() * 2); for(int i = 0, n = A.length(); i < n; i++) { if(A.charAt(i)<'A' || A.charAt(i)>'Z') { B.append(A.charAt(i)); } } return B.append(B).toString();`

Answer (score 0):

If just remove Capital characters from a string. Alternative solution just create another method **replaceAll()** + **regex**

```java
private static String removeCapitals(String A){
    if (!A.isEmpty() && !A.equals("")) {
        String B = A + A;
        String newStr = B.replaceAll("([A-Z])", "");
        return newStr;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s no point in checking for `.isEmpty()` *and* `.equals("")`, as both conditions are identical. Even worse, the entire idea of returning `null` when the string is empty, is more than questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter solution to your task.

```
String a = "ABcdEF";
String b = "";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
    if(a.toLowerCase().charAt(i) == a.charAt(i))
       b+=a.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(b);
```

By changing to .toUpperCase() you'll get rid of the lower case ones.